# Creating a subfolder in a folder opened with filedialog

Tags: python, file

I am currently trying to make a program for file organisation. I want my script to open a filedialog that asks for a sourcefolder where the files will be organised in based on their extension. After a sourcefolder has been selected, I want my script to make directories in that sourcefolder. I am a bit stuck on that last part.

```
import os
import shutil
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *

print('This is a program that organises files in a given directory')
print(''
      
      '')

print('Please select the folder in which you want to organise your files')

''' Source Folder '''
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()

source_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
```

The part above works just fine.

```
''' Create destination folders in the source folder '''
newpath1 = r'source_path\Images'
if not os.path.exists(newpath1):                     # check to see if they already exist
    os.makedirs(newpath1)

newpath2 = r'source_path\Documents'
if not os.path.exists(newpath2):
    os.makedirs(newpath2)

newpath3 = r'source_path\Else'
if not os.path.exists(newpath3):
    os.makedirs(newpath3)
```

This, however, does not. It just removes files, or places them somewhere I cannot find them.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

TLDR: *how to make directories in a sourcefolder submitted with filedialog.*

Comment: On which OP system do you work. Note that you wrote `os.mkdirs` instead of `os.mkdir`

Comment: I am using windows. it does not seem to work when I use os.mkdir instead of mkdirs

Comment: You might prefer to use the OS independent path composition strategies such as `os.path.join('source_path', 'Else')`. The same could be achieved with `Path` from `pathlib`.